# How to install a php extension on XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension

i tried using precompiled dlls as some tutorial said
but failed...
in the PECL site, i found some extensions but don't know how to use them in windows.
please help

Comment: Do you know what is the error when u tried to install them?

Comment: its not working nor showing in phpinfo()

Comment: Check this, <a href="http://www.barneyparker.com/building-php-pecl-extension-in-windows/">Building PHP PECL Extension in Windows</a>

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "failed"?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a big deal you have to search for the required dlls.
Once you find them put them under the extensions folder in your php folder of your local server . 
Then go to the php.ini file open it in your favorite editor find the extensions list 
which contained # tags which means commented , actually some of the extensions are open and some are commented, you have to ad your extension there with no # in starting or find your extension name there in the list and uncomment it by removing #.

Now restart your localserver your extension has been added.
Enjoy ;)

Comment: @Ario i think you are missing something can you name your localserver